# Want to add object to an array in a class

Tags: php, arrays, class, object

I want to add the object `$employee_1` to the array `$employees` and then output it with the function `get_employees`, but I get nothing. Why?

```
class Employee
{
    public $name;
    public $position;

    public function __construct($name, $position)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->position = $position;
    }
}

class Company
{
    private $employees = array();
    public function get_employees()
    {
        foreach ($this->employees as $employee) {
            echo sprintf('%s works as %s.',$employee->name,$employee->position);
        }
    }

    public function add_emp($emp)
    {
        array_push($employees, $emp);
    }
}

$company = new Company();
$employee_1 = new Employee('Lars', 'Developer');
$company->add_emp($employee_1);
$company->get_employees();
```

Comment: Try
array_push($this->employees, $emp);

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an antipattern.  `echo sprintf()` should always be replaced with the simpler and identically performing `printf()`.  I only ever call `array_push()` when I need to push more than one element into an array.  When only one element needs to be pushed, use `$this->employees[] = $emp;`.